# Saving CoreData in UITableViewController but UISlider data is only in the Prototype Cell - how do I pull this over in order to save to CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uitableview

I have created a tableviewcontroller, with a dynamic prototype cell.  Within this view the user has an option to type in a review of a location from a button press  as well as can rate the location on a scale of 1 to 10 with a UI Slider.  The review is done with a UIAlertController within the tableviewcontroller - but the UISlider is within the cell itself.  I am trying to save both pieces of data to core data within the tableviewcontroller.  But the UISlider rating value is not available within the tableviewcontroller - is there a way to reference it in tableview from the cell or do I need to have two separate save functions?  Here is some of my code thus far - within the tableview controller it doesn't recognize the variable assigned to the UISLider value in the prototype cell.  Thanks in advance for any help!

**In my tableviewcell:**

```
class WineryInfoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var ratingLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sliderbutton: UISlider!

@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    var ratingValue = Float(sender.value)
    var roundedRatingValue = roundf(ratingValue/0.5)*0.5
    ratingLabel.text = "\(roundedRatingValue)"

}
```

**in my tableviewcontroller**

@IBAction func save() {

```
    if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext {

        myRatingData = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("WineryReview", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as wineryReview

        myRatingData.wineryName = wineryNames
        //myRatingData.rating = ratingLabel.text  how do I call this for saving?
        myRatingData.review = myRatingEntry


        var e:NSError?
        if managedObjectContext.save(&e) != true {
            println("insert error: \(e!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
    }

    // If all fields are correctly filled in, extract the field value
    println("Winery: " + myRatingData.wineryName)
    println("Review: " + myRatingData.review)
    //println("Rating: " + ratingLabel.text!)  how do I call this for saving?

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new at Swift, but I think I may have an answer to a part of your dilemma. To reference the UISlider in your table cell, you can use 'tags' to get a reference to it.

For example:

`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(TableViewCellIdentifiers.someCell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell`

`let slider = cell.viewWithTag(100) as UISlider`

In the above example, I would have used assigned the UISlider with a tag of 100, so I am able to get a reference to it using the cell.viewWithTag(100).

Forgive me if this doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a WineryReview object into the cell and set its rating directly from sliderValueChanged.

In cellForRowAtIndex:

```
cell.wineryReview = myReviewData
```

In TableViewCell:

```
@IBOutlet weak var ratingLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sliderbutton: UISlider!

var wineryReview: WineryReview?

@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    var ratingValue = Float(sender.value)
    var roundedRatingValue = roundf(ratingValue/0.5)*0.5

    wineryReview.rating = roundedRatingValue

    ratingLabel.text = "\(roundedRatingValue)"
}
```

You could call save on the context from the TableViewController if you like. I did something very similar to this in a project.